# Start Activity Intent does not want to run

Tags: android, kotlin

good afternoon,  I wanna ask a question bout my code

Here the function that I have

```
fun Check_Key(key: String):Boolean{
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val response = ApiService.CheckKey(key)

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                var Json = response.body()?.keyCheck.toString()


                if (Json == key){
                    return@withContext true
                }else{
                    return@withContext false
                    Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

if (viewModel.Check_Key(key_check) == true) {
                val intent = Intent (this@Login,MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else{
                //do something
            }
```

So the general idea is to compare the parameters on the Check_Key function and then compare it to the JSON that I have receive and on my testing is already return True but for some reason, after it returns true the program does not want to start the intent Activity, is there anything that can be done to fix this or is my function usage is not appropriate? I'm still new to Kotlin so I hope I can get help from here.

Comment: have you debug inside this if else check? also any errors in log ?

Comment: Yes I have, I do put both of them with start activity but it still does not want to run regardless if the return value is true or false

Comment: Nevermind when I try to debug again turn out the answer below is right all along and it always return false first

Answer (score 0):

`launch` will run the piece of code in a detached (async) way. Your check function will always return false. Maybe you want to do something like:

```kotlin
fun Check_Key(key: String):Boolean{
    return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).runBlocking {
        val response = ApiService.CheckKey(key)

         return withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                var Json = response.body()?.keyCheck.toString()


                if (Json == key){
                    return@withContext true
                }else{
                    
                    Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())
                    return@withContext false
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())
                return@withContext false
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although the code is not the right answer for my problem but the idea is. thank you so much